# Parsing images from XML <enclosure>

Tags: android, xml, parsing

I am parsing text and images from XML file.
Everyting is ok with text. 
But when I start to parse images listview becomes empty.

```
    for (int j = 0; j < clength; j++) {

                        Node thisNode = nchild.item(j);

                        String theString = null;

                        String nodeName = null;

                        if (thisNode != null && thisNode.getFirstChild() != null) {
                                theString = thisNode.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();                          
                        }

                        nodeName = thisNode.getNodeName();

                        if ("title".equals(nodeName)) {                     
                                _item.setTitle(theString);                          
                            }

                        if ("pubDate".equals(nodeName)) {               
                                String formatedDate = theString.replace(" +0000", "");
                                _item.setDate(formatedDate);
                        }   

                        if (nodeName.equals("enclosure")) {
                               Element enclosure = (Element) thisNode;
                                    if (enclosure.hasAttr("url")) {

                                    String imageLink = (enclosure.attr("url"));
                                        _item.setImage(imageLink);
                                    }
                        }

}
```

So, as I understand, the problem is taking data from .
How can I do this in wright way?
THNX!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i solves this task by this way.

```
 String body = nodeToString(thisNode);

 int urlStart = body.indexOf("url=");
 int urlFinish = body.indexOf("length");

 String urlImage = body.substring(urlStart+5, urlFinish-2);

 _item.setImage(urlImage);
```

And method nodeToString:

```
private String nodeToString(Node node) {
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    try {
            Transformer t = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
            t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
            t.transform(new DOMSource(node), new StreamResult(sw));
    } catch (TransformerException te) {
        System.out.println("nodeToString Transformer Exception");
    }
      return sw.toString();
}
```